# Does anchorOffset work correctly with UIWebView?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I am trying to get the `anchorOffset` of text selected by the user in A `UIWebView`.  I have a short Javascript function (below) that is called when the user selects text and chooses an option from a custom contextual menu.

```
function textPosition()
{ 
    var text = window.getSelection();
    var x = text.anchorOffset;
    return x;
}
```

I have a simple paragraph displayed in the `UIWebView` starting with:

> This is a test sentence

Everything works as expected if I select a whole words... eg. if I select `This` the function returns `0`, if I select `sentence` the function returns `15`.

However if I move the handles on the selected text in the `UIWebView` the `anchorOffset` is different than expected.  Eg. Selecting portions in the order as follows in the first word , `this` returns the following:

`his` returns 4

`hi` returns 1

`Thi` returns 3

Furthermore this is different depending on the order that I change the selection:

`This` returns 0

`Thi` returns 0

`hi` returns 3

It appears that the `anchorOffset` is different depending on from which end of the selection  I alter the selection.

My questions are:

1. Am I making an obvious mistake?
2. Is this expected behaviour?
3. Is there something I can do to make the result consistent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now understand what I was doing wrong.  It came from my misunderstanding of what an `anchor` actually is.  I thought the `anchorOffset` referred to the the *first part* of a selection *geographically* but actually it relates to where the moused button was initially pressed (obviously not on a touch screen).  The `focusOffset` relates to where the mouse button was released.

A nicer explanation can be found here:

[mozilla developer site](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsISelection)

With regard to a `UIWebView` an initial selection will place the `anchor` geographically at the start of the selected range and the `focus` at the end.  However each time a selection handle is moved it becomes the `focus` and the other handle becomes the `anchor`.